# ¿actualizar estado de sesion en BD, si el usuario cierra el navegador?

Tags: php

chicos estoy aquí para saber quién me podría ayudar con el manejo $_SESSION PHP.
es decir: cuando el usuario se loguea se me actualiza la BD poniendo su estado a activo, y si el cierra sesión también se actualiza a desactivado, con esto valido que usuario está conectado y que no puede iniciar sesión más de una vez al mismo tiempo.

pero necesito saber cómo puedo actualizar su estado en la bd, si el usuario ha decidido irse de la página sin cerrar sesión manualmente, entonces necesito destruir esa sesión y también actualizar el estado en mi bd, para que así ese mismo usuario pueda iniciar sesión la veces que quiera, ya sea poruqe se cerró la sesión sola(por defecto PHP hace esto) o porque se le apago el pc, o se le fue el Internet, etc.

agradezco sus ayudas, y si hay otro metodo para lograr esto gracias.

Comment: osea es que estoy tratando de asegurarme de que un usario no inice sesion mas de una vez al mismo tiempo, y que tambien pueda iniciar sesion cada que quiere siempre en cuando  la repuesta de la BD, deje loguarse nuevamente, el problema esta, cuando ce cierra el navegador o se olvido cerrar sesion, la BD no se actualiza, no se que otro metodo sirva.

Comment: Deberías poner lo que has intentado hacer hasta ahora

Answer (score 1):

Con JavaScript y PHP lo puedes hacer posible,

Mediante el evento onbeforeunload puedes capturar el instante donde el usuario cierra tu página, y mediante una petición AJAX cambiar el estado de la base de datos

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  // Tu código
};
```

[Podrías seguir esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310559/notify-user-on-browser-close-only)

Comment: lo estoy probando con alert(); pero se me ejcuta cada vez que la pagina recarga o me voy de un sitio a otro en la misma pagina,como hago para que solo me funcion cuando en realidad voy a cerrar la pestaña o ventana de la pagina?

Comment: Ya actualicé la publicación con un link.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crearte una variable con la última conexión a la web. Y cada página que se visite, este campo se puede ir actualizando, si pasado este tiempo, no se ha cambiado la fecha, la siguiente visita o un job creado, te podría poner el estado inactivo.

Puedes revisar este enlace, donde comenta como poner los usuarios online en php

[Usuarios Online PHP](https://www.baulphp.com/usuarios-online-php/)